# Access violation writing location error in GLFW/GLEW opengl project

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, glfw, glew

I'm following a tutorial on setting up an opengl project with glfw and glew in visual studio 2022. When I run it, it starts to work as expected with a loading icon on my cursor, but after a few seconds it crashes with an `access violation writing location` error on the `glfwSwapBuffers` call.

I've enabled `glewExperimental` and called `glewInit` *after* `glfwMakeContextCurrent`. `glewInit` also does return `GLEW_OK`.
This is the source code

```
GLFWwindow* window;

/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())
    return -1;

/* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
if (!window)
{
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

/* Make the window's context current */
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return -1;

float positions[6] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
     0.0f,  0.5f,
     0.5f, -0.5f
};

unsigned int buffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

unsigned int shader = CreateShader(ReadFile("./vertex.shader"), ReadFile("./fragment.shader"));

// During init, enable debug output
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
glDebugMessageCallback(MessageCallback, 0);

/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Render here */
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```